# How do android generate R

Tags: java, android

What is the algorithm to generate **R**.
Will the param in **R** be always the **same**?

```
SharedPreferences preference = getPreference();
Object object = preference.getString(R.id.xxx);
```

I want to know that the value of R.id.xxx will change or not.

-----------------------try to ask the question more clearly-----------------

v1 = R.id.listview;

then clean the project;

v2 = R.id.listview;

will v1 = v2 all the time?

I tested like this.
Print the R.id.xxx,clean project and print the R.id.xxx again.
The result is the same.

But I don't know in different IDE, that value of R.id.xxx will change(the AAPT version is all the same or not).

Comment: **R** is an autogenerated file. NEVER touch it!!

Answer (score 1):

**Android R.java** is an auto-generated file by aapt (Android Asset Packaging Tool) that contains resource IDs for all the resources of res/ directory.

> **Note**: If you delete R.jar file, android creates it automatically.

Edit:

for more details about R.java , kindly refer [here](http://knowledgefolders.com/akc/display?url=DisplayNoteIMPURL&reportId=2883&ownerUserId=satya)

Comment: I edit my question.I think my question is more clear now.Your answer is now not enough for me.Hope get more detail,thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer.

Comment: Sorry,that article teach me a lot,but not answer my question either.I posted an answer myself,it's not detailed but answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.But unluckily, it's not in english.
Now I'll try to answer the question myself.If there's errors,please tell me.

---

There is a file in res/values/public.xml in the sdk directory.

The value will always read public.xml first.

So now you know if you didn't delete the file， the value will always the same.

But you delete it,I don't know what will happen.I'm afraid my application will have some error, so I didn't do the experiment.

---

If anyone has a link of article about how android generate R in English,comment or create a new answer thanks.

Comment: What if you create a new field in a layout with an id, or removing one ?

Comment: I tried add an id,the value is the same.And I read an article,it said to avoid Compatibility problems，the values will read from public.xml first.

Comment: Good to know, for Preference fragment, I had to create some ugly controler to get every preferences id, default value, ... it recover every data from R on generation, this was not perfect, I guess I could have use the generated value, with probably I small risk.

Comment: If you can read Chinese this article has more information.http://blog.csdn.net/luoshengyang/article/details/8744683

Comment: Nope, that's not going to help me :P but thanks for the link.